# Lambda in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby

I am not following [this change](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/2f92be21302db255f4357e95e9e1ce535b1a6a89). From:

```
longest_path_first = lambda do |host, location, _, _|
```

To:

```
longest_path_first = lambda do |(host, location, _, _)|
```

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>> al = lambda { |a,b,c| b }
>> bl = lambda { |(a,b,c)| b }
>> list = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,0,4]]
>> list.sort_by &al
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
    from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):4:in `each'
    from (irb):4:in `sort_by'
>> list.sort_by &bl
 => [[4, 0, 4], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Kind of illustrates why they've done it.

The reason of the change in Ruby is that they are trying to make lambdas consistent with normal methods:

```
>> def test(a,b,c); b; end
>> test [1,2,3]
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
    from (irb):16:in `test'
```

A good way to get around the not exactly pretty syntax is to use the new and shiny **Stab operator <sup>tm</sup>**:

```
cl = ->(a, b, c) { b }
```